# Does JDK have some optimizations for its own apis?

Tags: api, arraylist, jvm, java

Hi guys, I have copied the ArrayList source code from java.util package to my own package. But I found it running solwer than original java.util.ArrayList.

Test code:

```
@Test
public void jdkApiPerformance() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    java.util.ArrayList<Object> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Object>();
    long costTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("jdkPerformance cost " + costTime + "ns.");
}

@Test
public void myApiPerformance() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    question.jdk.ArrayList<Object> list = new question.jdk.ArrayList<Object>();
    long costTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("apiPerformance cost " + costTime + "ns.");
}
```

The outputs for this test as blow:

```
jdkPerformance cost 10263ns.
apiPerformance cost 1244158ns.
```

Obviously, my api runs slower than JDK api.

Then I added a @Before method for this test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    new java.util.ArrayList<Object>();
    new question.jdk.ArrayList<Object>();
}
```

The outputs for this case are changed:

```
jdkPerformance cost 9932ns.
apiPerformance cost 1324ns.
```

My api runs faster than JDK api!!?

I am really confused for this circumstance.Pls help me.Thanks.

Comment: You are experiencing, first hand, the dangers of micro benchmarking, especially when you don't set it up properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) using `System.nanoTime()` may give you distorted results because it's dependend on operating systems' scheduler granularity:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().

2) to have meaningful benchmarks, you have to *warm up* JVM first

3) for research you could use one of benchmarking libraries:

- http://code.google.com/p/caliper/
- http://perf4j.codehaus.org/
- http://jrat.sourceforge.net/

4) in general the answer to your question is: **yes**, in some circumstances Sun/Oracle's JVM hot-replaces some JDK code, like `Math.sqrt()` with implementations optimized for given OS/hardware.

Answer (score 1):

- The JVM loads classes on demand. Since java.util.ArrayList is such a fundamental class, it is likely to be already loaded before your benchmark begins, but question.jdkArrayList is probably used for the first time. This involves disk I/O to read the class file, which in itself takes orders of magnitude more time than creating a new instance. Additionally, java.util.ArrayList is more likely to have been optimized by the JIT compiler.
- System.nanoTime() has, according to its javadoc, "nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy". To use it to measure delays in the order of a microsecond is chancy at best. Additionally, it measures wall-clock time, not cpu time. If your cpu is otherwise occupied (say, be painting the console view in your development environment) that will count towards the time reported.